# How to layout tabular form in HTML

Tags: html, css, layout

How would you layout the following panel

1. div/spans
2. table
3. some grid
4. ?

[image]

Comment: For me, If my client don't need to support the ancient IE. I'll use flexbox because it's dynamic and easy to use. :D

Comment: I would use either Bootstrap or Foundation, they have a lot of different column classes you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** (easy to use, responsive grid system) or with a **table** (simpler solution). It depends on your requirements.

This would be the Bootstrap grid structure in your case:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13495717)

Comment: @worldofjr - Just edited my answer, thank you for the advice!